# convert custom text to html

Tags: php, html

Where can I find A code do this [image]

to convert colored an aligned text to html .

or what should search for to find something like that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for an HTML code editor script and this one may help you out : https://www.tinymce.com/
hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks I think that will work

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should learn how to code HTML by hand. However, barring that, I see that your screenshot is of the WordPress article editor. In your case I would suggest you make whatever stylistic changes you would like to the text, and then click the "Text" button on the top right, next to "Visual". This will give it to you in HTML format.

Comment: You misunderstood me and you are really underestimating  , I have a mail list in my website which admin can send an email to it (Broadcast) so I'm trying to make the admin able to customize it

Comment: @RamiZK I'm sorry for underestimating you, but your question was extremely sparse in details. Perhaps next time you might want to consider putting what you just put in your comment into your post. You'll get more relevant answers as people understand what you mean, and higher-quality answers as people understand that you're not a beginner.

Comment: Yes I will , But I tried to search on it all what I had is code editor like notepad++ and so on so I didn't know how to explain it .